# How to POST a tgz file in Python using urllib2

Tags: python, rest, post, urllib2

I would like to POST a .tgz file with the Python urllib2 library to a backend server. I can't use requests due to some licensing issues. There are some examples of file upload on stackoverflow but all relate to attaching a file in a form.

My code is the following but it unfortunately fails:

```
stats["random"] = "data"

statsFile = "mydata.json"
headersFile = "header-data.txt"
tarFile = "body.tgz"

headers = {}
#Some custom headers
headers["X-confidential"] = "Confidential"
headers["X-version"] = "2"
headers["Content-Type"]  = "application/x-gtar"

#Create the json and txt files
    with open(statsFile, 'w') as a, open(headersFile, 'w') as b:
        json.dump(stats, a, indent=4)
        for k,v in headers.items():
            b.write(k+":"+v+"\n")

#Create a compressed file to send
tar = tarfile.open(tarFile, 'w:gz' )
    for name in [statsFile,headersFile]:
        tar.add(name)
    tar.close()

#Read the binary data from the file
with open(tarFile, 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()

url = "http://www.myurl.com"
req = urllib2.Request(url, data=content, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=timeout)
```

If I use requests, it works like a charm:

```
r = requests.post(url, files={tarFile: open(tarFile, 'rb')}, headers=headers)
```

I essentially need the equivalent of the above for urllib2. Does anybody maybe know it? I have checked the docs as well but I was not able to make it work..What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious what your licensing issues are with Requests?

Comment: Not really licensing, but let's just say that there is not enough time to add Requests to the libraries to scan so as to be scanned for plagiarism and included to the binary for our release.

Comment: it's Apache2 licensed... and I have no idea what you need to scan for plagiarism, or what that even means in this context.

Comment: It needs to be scanned if it is included in the binary (we are statically including everything). I wish it was not, otherwise I wouldn't have to start digging around for many lines to replace a one liner!